# Multithreaded Core Data causing UI to hang

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I'm trying to execute a fetch against a fairly large data set (~60000 rows) in the background of my app. Despite using a separate thread, the UI noticeably hangs for a second or so whenever the fetch executes. Is my approach correct?

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        ABAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ABAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _rootManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        _backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_rootManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)fetch {
    [_backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ItemPhoto"];
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full_uploaded_to_server == 0 OR thumb_uploaded_to_server == 0"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = pred;
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modified" ascending:YES]; //Start at the back of the queue
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1;
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *photos = [_backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if(error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Looking in Instruments, it's definitely the call to `executeFetchRequest:` that's taking a long time to complete, and it does seem to be running on its own thread. Why would this be causing the UI to hang?

Thanks!

Comment: This code shouldn’t block the main thread directly. But at which method call does the main thread block?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the attributes in the predicate and sortdescriptor?

Comment: Adding an index on the modified field sped things up a fair bit. I've realised we don't really need the sort, so removing it entirely has massively helped things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any activity against the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is going to cause a block of other activities against it.  If you are fetching on one thread and another thread attempts to access the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` it is going to be blocked.

This can be solved in one of two ways:

1. Reduce the fetches so that the block is not noticeable.  Fetching in chunks, for example, can help to reduce this issue.
2. Make sure the data the UI is exposing is fully loaded into memory.  This will stop the main thread from trying to hit the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and getting blocked.

Depending on the application and the situation, one or the other (or both) of these implementations will remove the issue.

At the end of the day, background threads are not a silver bullet to solve fetch times.  If you are planning on fetching on a background thread just to put them onto the main thread you are going to be disappointed with the performance.

If you are fetching on the background thread for a non-UI purpose then consider reducing the size of each fetch or change the batch size, etc. to decrease the fetch time itself.

### Update

Warming up the cache doesn't work on iOS like it used to on OS X.  You can get the objects fully loaded into memory by configuring your `NSFetchRequest` so that the objects are fully loaded, relationships are loaded (if needed), your batch size and fetch size are large enough.  Naturally this needs to be balanced against memory usage.

Comment: How do you accomplish #2? I've heard that you can warm the row cache by running a query on a background thread, passing the ObjectIDs over to the main thread, and the re-run the query there. This isn't rely documented anywhere though. Is this just an implementation detail, or can we relying it? (Or am I totally wrong?)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!